# UML static factory

Tags: c#, class, static, uml

I'm looking for the correct way to depict the following situation in an UML class diagram:

```
public class DbTransaction
{
    private List<DbTask> taskList;

    public void buildTaskList() 
    {
       this.taskList = taskListFactory.buildTaskList();
    }
}

 public static class TaskListFactory
 {
    public static List<DbTask> buildTaskList()
    {
         List list = new List<DbTask>();
         return list;
    }
 }

public class DbTask
{
   .....
}
```

DbTransaction is associated with DbTask, but I'm unsure of the proper way to draw the relation to the static TaskList class.

Comment: Where is your definition of `taskListFactory`?

Comment: @ThomasKilian see the edit. Thanks for pointing out my oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct UML diagram has nothing to do with whether or not a factory exists, or whether or not the factory is a static class with a static method. The fact is that an instance of a `DbTransaction` maintains a list of instances of type `DbTask` in a class member variable called `taskList`. That implies your UML should show a `DbTransaction` class with a unidirectional association to a `DbTask` class. That unidirectional association should have an association-end property called `taskList` with a multiplicity of `0..*`.

If you like, you could also draw a dependency from the `DbTransaction` class to the `TaskList` class to indicate that it is called. You could also model the `buildTaskList()` operation as a static feature (by setting `isStatic=true`, which will show it as underlined on a class diagram). You could even be *really* specific by changing the client of that dependency from the `DbTransaction` class to its `buildTaskList()` operation and the supplier of that dependency from the `TaskList` class to its `buildTaskList()` operation.

Here is an example for you:

[image]

Comment: I think your answer is reasonable, drawing TaskList(Factory) as a dependency to DbTransaction. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In regards to Jim's answer I'd like to point out that I made the mistake in the OP to call the TaskListFactory class TaskList. Jim has created this UML diagram on the basis of that, and I corrected the OP afterwards. Thus, TaskList should be called TaskListFactory in the UML.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more possibilities to draw this.

1) Create a link between `DbTransaction` and `TaskList` and call the association uses

2) Create no link but write a note and say that this is a factory and is used by transactions

It also depends of you want to show the object oriented correct model or you want to show the behavior of the system.

I would suggest to use the option 2). when you not only want to display the behavior of these three components.

Comment: He's asking for the class diagram. Not the behavior.

Comment: Yeah than i would suggest solution 2)

Comment: There should *not* be an association between `DbTransaction` and `TaskList` because `DbTransaction` does not maintain a reference to it in a member variable. `DbTransaction` *does* maintain a member variable of type `DbTask` however.